# GestureService OnFlick

Tags: windows-phone-7, code-behind, gesture

How can I add the GestureService and a handler for the Flick event in code-behind (i.e. not in XAML)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, make sure you've added a reference to the [Silverlight Toolkit for Windows Phone 7](http://silverlight.codeplex.com), specifically the Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll assembly. Then make sure you have an XML namespace reference for the Microsoft.Phone.Controls namespace:

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

Then, add the `GestureService.GestureListener` to the control you want to handle gestures on:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="test" Text="Test">
    <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
        <toolkit:GestureListener Flick="TextBlock_Flick" />
    </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
</TextBlock>
```

Then you just need to implement your logic in the event handler.

**Update:** The above approach is for using the `GestureService` in XAML; to use the `GestureService` in code-behind you use the `GetGestureListener` method:

```
var listener = GestureService.GetGestureListener(this.test);
listener.Flick += this.TextBlock_Flick;
```

Comment: thanks, but I need to add this gesture service via code behind because I'm creating the control dynamically.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your question. I've updated the question to be more explicit and updated my answer with a solution for you.